# How to set focus on a newly inserted row in a asp:gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, setfocus

when data is inserted into database on button click, asp:gridview is filled and displayed.

i want to set focus on the newly inserted row. I am adding data one at a time. so only one row is to be focused at a time.. please help

**code in cs file:**

```
public void fillgridview()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = b.reg_gridview();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**Code in bal**

```
public void reg_insert(cat_bal b)
{
    d.insert(b);
}
```

**code in dal:**

```
public void insert( cat_bal b)
{
    string cmdtext = "Insert into category(Cat_id,Cat_name)values(@id,@name)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtext, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", b.Cat_id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", b.Cat_name);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [ASPxGridView.RowInserted](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowInsertedtopic) event?

Comment: can you show your code that you are using to retrieve the data either pre or post insert..? also perhaps you may want to alter your sql to filter on last updated date or some field that captures a date time otherwise you will need to have a return value that holds the ID of the last inserted row..then in your code when building / binding the data you would want to check for that Item ID and set focus on the entire grid line it's hard to tell without seeing any code what you are currently doing

Comment: I cant find event named  ASPxGridView.RowInserted.. There is an event RowCreated.. is it of any use??? @Brandon

Comment: I have added the code in my question.. @DJKRAZE

Comment: [ASPxGridView.RowInserted](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowInsertedtopic).

Comment: have you tried using a return / out parameter and then looking for the newly inserted row that way

Comment: hey @DJKRAZE can u plzz show me a sample code for using return/ out parameter..

Comment: try adding something like this to your existing code 
`SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("@NewId", SqlDbType.Int);
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(output) HttpContext.Current.Session["OutputId"] = output.Value;`

Comment: also what is `d` in this code mean `d.insert(b);`

Comment: d os object of dal class and b is object of bal class @DJKRAZE